# Wrong syntax for Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$SQL="SELECT first_name FROM people WHERE fname = '$fname' INSERT INTO (first_name) VALUES (fname)";
```

Anything wrong with this? Trying to insert a value from a user defined variable into a mysql table

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\wamp\www\Pxxxx\process.php on line 44

This is the error

$fname is a user defined variable
first_name is the column I'm trying to insert it into and it's in a table called people

Comment: Do a transaction if you want 2 statments.

Comment: Separate the two statements with a `;`

Comment: What are you trying to insert?  Are you trying to insert the result of the `SELECT`?  Do you mean: `INSERT INTO (first_name) SELECT first_name FROM people WHERE fname = '$fname'`?

Comment: @Floris: For security reasons, you can't run 2 statements in one `mysql_query` call (or whatever he's using).

Comment: Never actually knew that! @OP: it's not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What do you have on on line 44 in process.php?

Comment: $num_results=mysql_num_rows($result);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the order inverted.  It seems like you are looking for INSERT .. SELECT syntax (see MySQL documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO target_table (first_name)
SELECT fname
FROM people
WHERE fname = ?
```

It was unclear from your example what the name of the table you were trying to insert data into is, so I just listed it as `target_table` here.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement has to be reordered  like this:

```
"INSERT  INTO people (fname) SELECT '$fname' FROM dual;"
```

This will select the value of $fname from the  pseudo table "dual" and insert the value into "people".

Maybe this is more suitable:

```
"INSERT INTO people (fname) VALUES ('$fname');"
```

This snippet show you a simple insert statement.

Note: Please have a look for SQL Injection at Wikipedia. The code you are writing is open for these kinds of attacks. If you are writing PHP code, have a look for Prepared Statements and  mysqli to prevent  these attacks.