# PHP MySQL issue with INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

```
$SQL="INSERT INTO first_name VALUES (fname) SELECT first_name FROM people WHERE fname = '$fname'";
```

I'm trying to insert the value 'fname' which is $fname (variable defined by a user) into the column 'first_name'

It's not adding anything but not displaying any errors. Syntax problem?

Comment: Is your table name `first_name`?

Comment: `mysql_error` is the function for returning errors in your query. If I have to read one more post about this I am going to scream.

Comment: Are you saving the same value in 2 different tables?

Comment: As another aside, it's highly unsafe to just stick that ol' `$fname` into the query. Since you're using it, I'm assuming that you're using the mysql_* family of functions, [which is BAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). The question that I just linked also has resources on alternatives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong syntax for Mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643328/wrong-syntax-for-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

you don't need  `VALUES()` here

```
INSERT INTO first_name
SELECT first_name 
FROM people WHERE fname = '$fname'
```